# Refresh column sum on search in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I am populating a table using ng-repeat and the data is coming from json with a request. I am calculating sum of each column and when I search something in the search box then the table shrinks. I want to refresh the sum on search. Following is my code

```
     <input type="text" class="form-control glyphicon glyphicon-search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchCpu" style="width:100%; margin:10px;"/>

    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" >
 <thead>
    <tr>
     <th class="totalHead" ng-repeat="(headIndex,columns) in cpuData.columns track by $index">{{columns}}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>  
        <td class="totalBody">Total</td>
        <td class="totalBody">------</td>
            <td class="totalBody" ng-repeat="column in cpuData.columns track by $index" ng-if="$index > 1">{{sum(column) | number:2}}</td>
      </tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="object in filteredItems.data | filter:searchCpu">
        <td ng-repeat="(IndexX, cpuValue) in object">{{cpuValue}}</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>  
     <td class="totalBody">Total</td>
     <td class="totalBody">------</td>
         <td class="totalBody" ng-repeat="column in filteredItems.columns" ng-if="$index > 1">{{sum(column) | number:2}}</td>
     </tr>
<tbody>
  </table>
```

app.js

```
    $scope.projCpu = function(){
$http({
url: hostName+'SASStoredProcess/do?&_program=/Stored+Processes/mgmt/services/projectCPUs&stg_id='+hostNameFactory.envInsId,
    method: 'GET',
}).then(function successCallback(projectCpu) { 
   $scope.cpuData = projectCpu.data;
   res = projectCpu.data
   $scope.filteredItems = angular.copy(projectCpu.data);
       $scope.sum = function(key) {
        return $scope.filteredItems.data.reduce(function(acc, curr) { 
    return acc + (curr[key] * 1); 
     },
   0);
  } 
 $scope.$watch("searchCpu", function (newValue) {
     //$scope.test = newValue;
     //$scope.data = $scope.cpuData;
     //cope.search = filterFilter($scope.cpuData.data, newValue);
     $scope.filteredItems.data = filterFilter($scope.cpuData.data, newValue);
  });  
     });      
}
```

JSON data

```
    {"columns":["Environment", "Project","APP1","APP2","APP3","APP4","APP5"], "data":[ {"Environment":"BIAA DEV", "Project":"1_frd","APP1":"0","APP2":"0","APP3":"0","APP4":"0","APP5":""} , {"Environment":"BIAA DEV", "Project":"65juju7","APP1":"0","APP2":"0","APP3":"0","APP4":"0","APP5":""} , {"Environment":"BIAA DEV", "Project":"a_final","APP1":"0","APP2":"0","APP3":"0.3","APP4":"0","APP5":""} , {"Environment":"BIAA DEV", "Project":"a_prod_final","APP1":"0","APP2":"0.2","APP3":"0","APP4":"0","APP5":""} , {"Environment":"BIAA DEV", "Project":"dzjrzrjtr","APP1":"0","APP2":"0","APP3":"0","APP4":"0","APP5":""} , {"Environment":"BIAA DEV", "Project":"final_test","APP1":"0","APP2":"0","APP3":"0","APP4":"0","APP5":""} , {"Environment":"BIAA DEV", "Project":"gugus2","APP1":"0","APP2":"0","APP3":"0","APP4":"0","APP5":""} , {"Environment":"BIAA DEV", "Project":"gugus3","APP1":"0","APP2":"0","APP3":"0","APP4":"0","APP5":""} , {"Environment":"BIAA DEV", "Project":"mgmt","APP1":"0.01","APP2":"0","APP3":"0","APP4":"","APP5":""} ]}
```

I have implemented this without request but I am doing something wrong while doing request for json data. I understand that the sum and watch functions should be outside of request response body. Following is the jsfiddle where I am implementing this without requesting json data.

https://jsfiddle.net/ze1jyp22/17/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't see any Sum colum in your fiddle. Where do you want your sum to be displayed

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari, first and the last row is actually the sum. If you see these two rows, they are adding columns